# Search values using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, search

```
int searchval(int *arr, int size, int key)
{
  int val;

  for(int y = 0 ; y < size ; y ++  )
  {

    cout<<arr[y]<<endl; // Re-list the array of numbers
    if(arr[y] == key)
      int val =  key;
  }
  return val;

}
```

I have randomly generated the numbers and put them into an array in the `main()` function. The issue comes in the search algorithm. I'm using pointers so I'm guessing my syntax is off. I'm not sure what the problem is however I feel it's an easy one. Anyone can help me out?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Turn on more compiler warnings.

Comment: When I enter a number that is in the array, the searchval function keeps returning 0. How do i fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two different variables, both named `val`. The one inside the `if` statement is only in that scope.

Simple remove the declaration of the `val` variable inside the `if`, and only use assignment:

```
if (...)
    val = key;
```

Comment: Thanks ! That was the problem

Comment: ALSO: you probably want to ```val = y``` and not ```val = key```.